# Hide child component/route until called in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I understand that the child component is called inside the parent `render()` function, but is there a way to hide it until it is called, for say, by a button.

Say this is your router file

```
{
    path:'/products',
    name: 'Products',
    component: Products,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':subtype',
        name: 'Subtype',
        component: ItemSubtypes
      }
    ]
  },
```

Now say I want to hide Subtype until you click a button to go to `/products/subtype`. Is there a way to do this or do I need to not use child routes?

The reason for this is that when you visit just `/products` the component of Subtype has no data and is thus empty. I would rather not render it yet if possible.

Comment: Usually, a `v-if` on components should suffice to halt rendering until things are ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-if`, until data is loaded the condition will be false. Or set a flag to truthy after button click, initially being falsey.

Comment: So should I run a v-if on the component tag

Comment: How would i reset the data if I want to go back to the first parent page so that it stays hidden until button is clicked?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand, can you elaborate kindly?

Comment: Say I click the button and it appears, but it updates it using a variable, so setting isShown to true, but when I navigate back isShown is still true, so how do I restore its value to false upon page load or component load without messing up the button click and child component render?

Comment: so on navigation, why don't you set it to false again. you have isShown boolean already?

Comment: What do you mean on navigation?

Comment: does the route change? You said when you navigate back, that navigation. If route changes you can do on that and if there is only button click and you receive data, so if data is empty toggle the boolean value.

Comment: yes the route changes, but if use the `updated` or any other hook it either doesn't update right or updates when I show the child component so it doesn't work right.

Comment: kindly post your code, if you can setup stackblitz or something so I can have a look